# Do you really want to create a new tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface, tag-creation

I have been cleaning up tags on SU today and accidentally created a new tag by hitting return when the tag suggestion drop-down highlighted the tag I wanted. I probably should have pressed tab instead....

Anyway, **I would like a confirmation when a new tag is created**, both as a way to avoid stupid mistakes and as a place to add a few pointers on tag creation.

For example:

> Tag **FOO** does not exist, are you sure you want to create it.
>
> Please make sure that
>
> 1. there isn't an existing tag or sets of tags that can be used instead.
> 2. there isn't an alternative spelling already in use
> 3. it's not a meta-tag
> 4. isn't comprised of numbers only
> 5. it's spelled correctly
>
> before you proceed

Comment: I can see you don't have 10k abilities on any site yet -- I'm putting it out there that I would like this feature to also be implemented for the in-page retagging tool (although the message can be terse since 10k's should know what they're doing).

Comment: I think this should only show up on sites that don't have the lower rep limits of beta.  People often need to create tags on new sites.

Comment: Yeah its a very good suggestion.Not very necessary but will be a nice feature if added to stack exchange sites

Comment: Perhaps the confirmation message could automatically show tags with similar names (defining "similar" is left as an exercise).

Comment: +1 from me. I seem to have created [meta-tag:specific-tag] accidentally (I mis-remembered that it already existed). I was surprised that there wasn't even a tiny "are you sure"? (But I'm flattered, that SO trusts me that much ;-))

Answer (score 2):

I think if they just gave a small window of time that you could delete tags you just created, it would solve most problems that you'd need the warning for.