# Removal of misspelled tag javascrpt

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, spelling

Found a misspelled tag [javascrpt](/questions/tagged/javascrpt) on SO tonight.

Possible choices(in my opinion)

- Remove the tag.
- Merge the tag with correct one [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

There are no questions in the tag, so deletion seems to be the most obvious of choices.

Comment: This [tag:javascrpt] has been created twice(atleast). Shouldn't there be a restriction on such typos? [Related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/deleting-misspelt-tags)

Comment: Like this? [Do you really want to create a new tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66504/do-you-really-want-to-create-a-new-tag) It's way too easy to accidentally create a misspelled tag.

Comment: `javscript`, `javacript`, `javacsript`, etc, etc, etc.  If we don't get two misspeelings of JS a week, something is *wrong*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no questions tagged with this tag - it will get cleaned up in our automatic job.

When you see such a tag, correct it on any question you see it - it will get deleted automatically within 24 hours (usually).