# typo in tag leads to bad new tag and low question activity

Tags: feature-request, tags

I typed in a detailed question but typed into the tag field "sql-serverr" as a tag, which then got auto created.  This led to no "busy" tags being associated to the question.

Maybe if the distance between an existing tag and a newly created tag is only a single character, it should auto-correct?

Comment: Why don't you select the correct tag from the listed tags instead of writing manually? When you type `sql` it will show you `sql-server` in a suggested list.

Comment: this problem is always happening when the tag auto search was disabled

Comment: And, in this case, is it so hard to edit your question with the correct tag afterwards? You do proof-read your question, right? =)

Comment: I submit the "feature request" in the mindset that they ultimately want the most idiot-proof possible application... I've been using the system for something like 2 years now and it'll probably be another 2 before I did that again.. it was just meant to log a user experience in the chance it might be helpful down the road

Comment: We're not criticising that you submitted a feature-request, we're just constructively disagreeing with the feature you're requesting. =)

Answer (score 3):

As replied on one of my older(and similar question [Removal of misspelled tag javascrpt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169407/212576) )

> When you see such a tag, correct it on any question you see it - it
>   will get deleted automatically within 24 hours (usually).

---

As per your feature-request on auto-correction of such tags, there is a possibility that someone somewhere decides to (let's say) create an entirely new programming language and names it **phpp**. How will you resolve creation of such tags now?

Comment: The feature, if it existed, should be accompanied by a confirmation question. "phpp" is going to be changed to "php" with two buttons, "Yes", and "No, I actually want to create a new phpp tag." Not that I support it, but if it _did_ exist, it should work this way.